# How to convert an NSString to a char?

Tags: objective-c

I know this was answered before, but it was about 7 years ago and it seems like it is not relevant anymore.

What I am currently doing (isn't working, seems like it's probably irrelevant now)

```
NSString sPath = [path string];

#define BUFSIZ 256
char cPath[BUFSIZ];
[sPath getCString:cPath maxlength:BUFSIZ encoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
```

The errors I am getting:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'NSUTF8Encoding'

error: instance method '-getCString:maxlength:encoding:' not found (return type defaults to 'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Objective-C is a case sensitive language. You are using the right method, it's just spelled wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUTF8Encoding` doesn't exist. Here is a list of `NSString` encodings:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencoding?language=objc

You probably want `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. All of the foundation classes and their arguments are documented online as well as in Xcode including [`getCString:maxLength:encoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1415702-getcstring).

Objective-c is also a case sensitive language. Methods, objects, and variables all need the correct spelling including the correct case.

Comment: Thanks, I probably should have looked at encodings for NSString before I asked.